# Determining which vectors are solutions of a given system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, solution-verification

Determine which vectors are solutions of the system.

\begin{align*}
& \hphantom{+}3x-2y-5z = \hphantom{+}4 \\
& \hphantom{+}2x+4y-\hphantom{1}z = \hphantom{+\llap{$0$}}2 \\
& {-}4x-8y+9z = {-}6
\end{align*}

**I** $\langle 4,-1,2 \rangle$

Substitute **I** into the last equation which evaluates to $\displaystyle 10=-6$, a contradiction.

Hence, **I** is not a solution.

**II** $\langle 4,2,0 \rangle$

Substitute **II** into the first equation which evaluates to $\displaystyle 8=4$, a contradiction.

Hence, **II** is not a solution.

**III** $\langle -\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{4},-2 \rangle$

Substitute **III** into the second equation which evaluates to $\displaystyle -18=-6$, a contradiction.

Hence, **III** is not a solution.

**IV** $\langle -1,-1,-1 \rangle$

Substitute **IV** into the second equation which evaluates to $\displaystyle 5=2$, a contradiction.

Hence, **IV** is not a solution.

---

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your calculations and they are exact. You probably could have double checked yourself. Believe in yourself!